# Audio effect that adds a natural sounding vibrato to a vocal track

Tags: sound-effects, vocals, pitch-shifting

I'm looking for an audio effect (on Windows) to add a natural sounding vibrato to a vocal track which has virtually no vibrato.

I don't mean the singer didn't use much vibrato, I mean I have artificially reduced the amount using Melodyne and now I want add a *different kind* of vibrato.

The reason here is that I have a sample library of female voice samples, but I wanted to extend the range a bit by pitch shifting the lowest and highest samples by up to a few semitones (which, using the original vibrato, still sounds fairly convincing). On a pitch-shifted sample I need to have a different vibrato than the original, otherwise it becomes extremely obvious (artificial sounding) if you play two notes together with the same kind of vibrato.

The vibrato implemented in Auto-Tune is not so great for this purpose; no one sings with a vibrato of a fixed rate like 1Hz or below (I think, if they are not deliberately adding vibrato like in classical singing). I also don't know how to reasonably select different rates for the different samples. Vibrato (after the attack phase) sounds/looks more a like random walk, so ideally I want to find a plugin that realizes something close to that.

---

Alternatively, I thought about the possibility of using pitch recognition on another vocal track (e.g. one I record myself) to recognize the vibrato and "transfer" it to the sample I need vibrato on. But this is hypothetical, I have no idea whether something like this is even remotely possible.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Ideally, you could have the original vibrato, just altered slightly to make it sound less like the original. The only thing I can think of is using a pitch-warping tool to apply it manually if it's possible, or to adjust the original vibrato. Or maybe you could just _attenuate_ the original vibrato rather than removing it completely?

Comment: @MarcW Do you have any tool for pitch-warping in mind? I have a graphic tablet, perhaps I could draw convincing curves with that (if some program allows that) - Yes, I reduced the vibrato of the original instead of removing it completely. But ultimately, I just need another "vibrato curve" with no obvious relationship to the original. If you play two notes together, where the vibrato (modulo the actual note) only differs by a constant factor, I believe this becomes very obvious to the listener.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your dilemma. Unfortunately, I don't know of any pitch-warping tool that is _that_ customizable. I thought something like Melodyne would do it. But if I come across anything, I'll let you know.

Comment: To understand correctly, you want a vibrato that follows the given Hz rate thats decided by the note of the singer?

Comment: @frcake One basically separates the actual pitch as a function of time (e.g. in cents, i.e. logarithmically) into "note + vibrato", i.e. the note meant (that's a constant) plus the deviations pitch-wise from this note (that's not constant). I want to switch out the "vibrato" part with something else.

Comment: I would approach the problem by dividing the sound depending on the x factor and apply differemt variations of y factor, for example divide the pitch and add different modulation effects on each result and allways doing it in parallel with something. Very big problems in audio are solved by dividing stuff and applying different stuff, well theres a lot of "stuff" here, but im just suggesting something, ill follow this question and maybe i can understand more about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @frcake The sum "note + vibrato" doesn't refer to an audio signal but to pitch. You can't simply separate and mix them together later which would be summing the signals, not the pitches (this is something that Melodyne can somwhat do, but only rudimentarily). And I'm being imprecise too, it isn't really a sum: The "note" part also carries an actual audio signal with it. It's more like: the "vibrato" part modulates the "note" part and in doing so the absolute pitch of the result is a sum in this fashion.

Comment: @StefanPerko don't get me wrong , I'm not judging your question or how well you put it. I'm the one who doesn't get the full image :) maybe I'll do later on :)

Comment: @frcake Sure, I'm just trying to explain it as best as I can.